# Новорождённый или новоро́жденный?

Tags: фонетика

Как правильно: "новорождённый" или "новоро́жденный"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Считаю "новорождённый" (и мертворождённый) единственно верным.
Вариант новорОжденный приводит (как разговорный) только БТС Кузнецова. Рискну не согласиться. Тем более что Зарва и Аванесов дают этот вариант как неправильный.

Comment: Принимается!

Answer (score 1):

Правильно **новорождЁнный**. Вариант *новор**О**жденный* - разговорный.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно новорождЁнный. В словаре Резниченко И.Л. вариант новорОжденный даётся как неправильный.